# How to rename a DAG in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow

I've been assessing Airflow the last few days as a possible replacement tool for our ETL workflows and found some interesting behaviour when a DAG is renamed in Airflow.

If I have a dag in a file called **hello_world.py**

```
dag = DAG('hello_world', description='Simple DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2017, 11, 1), catchup=True)
```

And this dag has been executed for 10 days in November, I then decide that I simply want to change the name of the dag to 'yet_another_hello_world' e.g.
in the same file **hello_world.py**

```
dag = DAG('yet_another_hello_world', description='Simple DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2017, 11, 1), catchup=True)
```

Im simply doing a rename of the job, not change to the business logic etc.  When this is deployed into Airflow, it is automatically picked up and registered as a new job, so there are now 2 jobs visible in the DAG view

- hello_world
- yet_another_hello_world

Becuse of **catchup=True** in the DAG definition, the scheduler automatically see's this change and registeres a new job *yet_another_hello_world* it then continues to backfill the missing executions from the 1st of November. It also continues to leave the existing **hello_world** job intact.

Ultimately, I want this to be a rename of the existing job and not preserve the old hello_world job. Is there a way to indicate to airflow that this is a simple rename?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a best practice, it is always recommended to create a new dag file when you want to change your dags' name, schedule_interval or start_date.

Comment: Thanks for response, creating a new file and ultimately new job id would guarantee that i Lose the history of the job executions from the previous job tho.  Id like to retain that history on the new job name if thats possible

Comment: You need only to change the dag id, not the job's id. For a specific DAG's history, you can, from the airflow metadatabase,  change the old dag_id with the new dag_id